# Matlab's quadprog equivalent in python?

Tags: optimization, svm, python

For my SVM algorithm I need to do an optimization in standard QP form.

In Matlab I would use 'quadprog' with the 'interior-point-convex' algorithm from the Optimization toolbox.

What is an equivalent (preferably free for acadamic use) library for python?

Answer (score 1):

One such (commercial) package is [MOSEK](http://mosek.com/products/mosek/). It has [native Python bindings](http://mosek.com/products/product-overview/mosek/python/) and is also supported by [CVXOPT](http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/).

Comment: Could you maybe give an example how this is done in MOSEK? I don't seem to find it in their documentation very well

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PyIMSL Studio](http://www.roguewave.com/products/imsl-numerical-libraries/pyimsl-studio.aspx), which wraps the [IMSL C numerical libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMSL_Numerical_Libraries) in Python using [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html). It is free-as-in-beer for academic and non-commercial use. For your question, two routines are documented in Chapter 8: Optimization of the Math Guide:

- quadProd - Solves a quadratic programming problem subject to linear equality or inequality constraints.
- constrainedNlp - Solves a general nonlinear programming problem using a sequential equality constrained quadratic programming method.